# Problema com INSERT PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Olá amigos sou muito leigo em PDO e gostaria da ajuda dos amigos para tentar criar um INSERT que cadastre um nome de fonte na tabela fontes do BD.
Seguinte, eu criei esse código abaixo, baseado no código do UPDATE que esta funcionando:

```
    <form name="enter" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=site', "root", "");
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare ('INSERT INTO fontes (font) VALUES (:font)');
    $stmt->execute(array(':font' => $font));

    echo 
    "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= ../cadastros/cad_fonte.php'>
    <script language='javascript'>
    window.alert('Dados alterados com sucesso!');
    </script>";
    }
    ?>

    <h3>Caso a fonte desejada não esteja listada, cadastre-a agora!</h3><br />

    <input type="text" name="font" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="enter" value="Cadastrar" />
```

Peço aos amigos que me ajudem a fazer um código que funcione para que eu possa efetuar o cadastro.

Desde já meus agradecimentos.

Comment: Qual o erro encontrado?

Comment: Amigos, descobri o porque não estava conseguindo cadastrar a fonte.
Estava faltando essa linha no código.

     '$font = $_POST['font'];'
Valeu galera pela atenção.